# Have fancyBox dynamically update based on gallery folder

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I'm trying to find an image gallery with lightbox that I can use to show off images at a party. I really like the look and feel of [fancyBox](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox) but it lacks an important feature I need - to update the gallery as images come into a folder.

I'll be taking pictures through the night and each time I dump more pictures into a gallery folder, I want them to be automatically picked up... similar to the way scripts like [sfpg](https://sye.dk/sfpg/) do, but can't work out how to acheive this with fancyBox.

Comment: You may need server-side scripts as since you can't scan directorys with javascript only.

Comment: You may want to check this http://www.picssel.com/create-a-filtered-image-gallery-with-jquery-and-fancybox-part-2-create-image-thumbnails-with-php/